# Conditional formatting on cells to check if they are equal

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to apply a formula to change color of both cells if they are not equal and if they are equal.

I tried conditional formatting in excel but it did not give me the required solution.
I want something like below:

[please click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTq4c.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is wrong in the screenshot? It seems your conditions worked as expected?

Comment: it was not dynamic, it was something that I had to fill in manually for the porpose of what I exactly want.

Comment: "[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812)"
"[I downvoted because an image of your exception isn't helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/)"

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to apply dollars in the conditional formatting formula. The dollars need to be in front so the formatting is applied properly.

Select the range you want to apply conditional formatting > Conditional formatting > New Rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format:

[image]

And do it again but then with <> in between and make it red.
There you go.

Comment: I got it, appreciate the help. Thanks